# RTC is not saving time after hwclock

Tags: linux, shutdown, clock

So I'm having quite a bit of trouble trying to get my system to set the hardware clock's time. Here is what I did just now, everything has worked, right? The first and last command seem to indicate that I have changed the hardware clock's time.

```
[omed@localhost ~]$ sudo hwclock -r
Fri 19 Aug 2011 12:15:59 PM MDT  -0.407669 seconds
[omed@localhost ~]$ sudo ntpdate 0.pool.ntp.org
19 Aug 12:16:21 ntpdate[1816]: step time server 76.73.0.4 offset 94694401.172566 sec
[omed@localhost ~]$ date
Tue Aug 19 12:16:26 MDT 2014
[omed@localhost ~]$ sudo hwclock -w
[omed@localhost ~]$ sudo hwclock -r
Tue 19 Aug 2014 12:16:41 PM MDT  -0.329495 seconds
```

However, a few notes about the device is that it's an intel Q7 (image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGNvf.png))
module plugged into a carrier board designed by someone else. The RC uses a battery that isn't actually on the device, but comes from a battery on the carrier board. **The RTC does store and save time set through the BIOS**, however, if I power the system off and back on (without doing standard shutdown, literally just cutting power to the board), after logging in, this happens:

```
[omed@localhost ~]$ sudo hwclock -r
Fri 19 Aug 2011 12:23:02 PM MDT  -0.580141 seconds
```

issuing a `poweroff` command and then power-cycling the device **does** save the time to the RTC successfully, however doing a 'clean' shutdown is not an option, what does linux do during shutdown that it doesn't do when I run hwclock? The calibration time and drift time from the RTC also show the correct date for drift/calibration (August 2014, as below), but doesn't actually display the correct time (for some reason it still thinks it's 2011).

```
[omed@localhost ~]$ sudo hwclock -r -D
...
Last drift adjustment done at 1408472197 seconds after 1969
Last calibration done at 1408472197 seconds after 1969
...
Time read from Hardware Clock: 2011/08/19 18:26:45
Hw clock time : 2011/08/19 18:26:45 = 1313778405 seconds since 1969
Fri 19 Aug 2011 12:26:45 PM MDT  -0.877045 seconds
```

The system is a special distro based around embedded systems (timesys bowler 14), however, it is based on fedora 14 and is close enough that it can be treated as fedora.

Comment: I removed the `fedora` tag as this is very unlikely to be a distro specific issue.

Comment: What options is `hwclock` called with during poweroff? I know some x86 machines require `--directisa`, for example. I think the options are in a file under `/etc/sysconfig` on Fedora, if not they'll be elsewhere under `/etc` (on Debian, it's `HWCLOCKPARS` in `/etc/default/hwclock`).

Comment: Coming from the initscripts (rc.d), it's just `hwclock --systohc` and nothing else. In `/etc/sysconfig` all I see see is an ntpdate option to sync the hardware clock, set to no, which is **OK**